# Can't execute a JavaScript event using 'onclick' button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to execute 'select' function via `onclick` but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function select() {
      document.getElementById('select').disabled = true;        
  }
</script>

<input type="button" id="select" value="OK" onclick="select()">
```

Comment: Does your page have any other JavaScript errors? Have you tried using a different id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mySelect() {
        document.getElementById('myselect').setAttribute('disabled');        
    }
</script>

<input type="button" id="myselect" value="OK" onclick="mySelect()">
```

Two things:

a) avoid using internal names for functions or variables. select is an html reserved word; and

b) the right way to set is using the setAttribute.

Done! (and tested).

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the name of the Function from select to something else.
select is html reserved word so doesn't work.

Comment: to check working if the function is working or not, put alert() in your method.

Comment: -1 "select" is not a javascript keyword.  If I could, I'd -2 for your advocating the use of alert() in your subsequent comment.  Always test using console.log (ff/chrome/IE9+ support this method).